# jasper reports - msg function not accepting more than 4 parameters including pattern

Tags: jasper-reports, properties-file, msg

So it seems i can't create a string from properties file with more than 3 parameters plus the pattern:

```
msg(str("lifeletter."+$P{COD_DOC}+".message"),$P{PR_YEAR},$P{MODULE_NAME},$F{benefit_value},$F{accumulated_value})
```

I get this error:

> The method msg(String, Object, Object, Object) in the type JREvaluator is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, String, String, String)
>                   value = msg(str("lifeletter."+((java.lang.String)parameter_COD_DOC.getValue())+".message"),((java.lang.String)parameter_PR_YEAR.getValue()),((java.lang.String)parameter_MODULE_NAME.getValue()),((java.lang.String)field_benefit_value.getValue()),((java.lang.String)field_accumulated_value.getValue())); //$JR_EXPR_ID=10$

If i remove the last param(accumulated_value {3}) it will work

here is the .properties file entry:

> letter.product.message   = Caro Cliente, Vimos pela presente informar que, em {0} , foi atribuida participação nos resultados ao seu {1} no valor de {2}. \
>                                  Desta forma, o valor acumulado atual da participação nos resultados é de {3}.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the java class MessageFormat:

```
new MessageFormat(str("pattern")).format(new Object[]{"value 1","value 2", "value 3","value 4"})
```

Comment: You can also pass an array to the msg function.  As in msg("message {0} {1} {2} {3} {4}", new Object[]{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"})

Comment: I think i tried that solution and i got an identical error.

Comment: Works fine for me.